# Getting Height and Width of Image in Java without an ImageObserver

Tags: java, image-processing, awt, dimensions

I am trying to get the `height` and `width` of images (via a url) in Java without an ImageObserver.
My current code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File xmlImages = new File("C:\\images.xml");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlImages));
    File output = new File("C:\\images.csv");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.contains("http")){
            URL url = new URL(line.)
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
            sb.append(line + ","+ img.getHeight(null) + "," + img.getWidth(Null) + newline);            
        }

    }

    br.close();
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    bw.close();
}
```

When i go into debug mode I am able to see that the image was loaded and I can see the `height` and the `width` of the image, but i can't seem to return them. The `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods require an Image Observer, which i don't have. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) to handle the loading of the image for you.

Change

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
sb.append(line + ","+ img.getHeight(null) + "," + img.getWidth(Null) + newline);
```

to

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
sb.append(line + ","+ img.getIconHeight(null) + "," + img.getIconWidth(Null) + newline);
```

The main change is to use `ImageIcon`, and the `getIconWidth`, `getIconHeight` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realised this and came back to answer the question myself :P. Thanks alot though.

Answer (score 2):

Following should work

```
   Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(image_url);
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
   int height = icon.getIconHeight();
   int width = icon.getIconWidth();
   sb.append(line + ","+ height + "," + width + newline);
```

Answer (score 0):

One can get width and height using following code if there is difficulty in retrieving URL.

```
try {

File f = new File(yourclassname.class.getResource("data/buildings.jpg").getPath());
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
int height = image.getHeight();
int width = image.getWidth();
System.out.println("Height : "+ height);
System.out.println("Width : "+ width);
              } 
catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**Note:** *data* is folder in /src containing images.

Credit goes to [Getting height and width of image in Java](http://javachamp.blogspot.com/2010/04/getting-height-and-width-of-image-in.html)