# Fill rectangle with image in Java

Tags: java

How can I fill the following rectangle using an image? Can anyone help me please?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         setOpaque(false);  
        //Paint a filled rectangle at user's chosen point.
        if (point != null) {
            g.drawRect(0, 0,
                       rectWidth - 1, rectHeight - 1);
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillRect(1, 1,
                       rectWidth - 2, rectHeight - 2);
            }}
```

I tried this code but I couldn't find a way to make it work:

```
File imageFile = new File("duck.jpg");
BufferedImage img;
Graphics2D graph = img.createGraphics();
graph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graph.fill(new Rectangle(1, 2, rectWidth, rectHeight));
graph.dispose();
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("duck.jpg"));
```

Comment: What do you create the variable `imageFile` for? Also, do you know what `dispose` means and did you read the comment of the method of the same name?

Comment: Do you get a `NullPointerException` on this line by the way.. `Graphics2D graph = img.createGraphics();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load an image into an Image object (like BufferedImage) and then call

`graphics.drawImage()`

on that image, giving the coordinates and other info.

Look in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) for more info

Comment: I've tried your idea but it throws me an error: `Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("duck.jpg");
            int w = img.getWidth(null);
            int h = img.getHeight(null);
            BufferedImage bi = new
            BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            //Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);`

Comment: It's not an error, it's the line of code that throws it. Post the error.

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0` and many many others after it

Comment: getWidth returns -1 if the width is not yet known. It means that the image is not loaded yet. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336558/getting-height-and-width-of-image-in-java-without-an-imageobserver