# What is the purpose of the ImageObserver field when getting the height and width of an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageobserver

Java has this method: `getWidth(ImageObserver observer)`

It returns the Width of an image. This method seems simple enough until you get to the part where an ImageObserver is requiered. What is the purpose of the ImageObserver as a parameter. Is there any other way around this?

Note that I can't just use an ImageIcon as mentioned here: [Getting Height and Width of Image in Java without an ImageObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336558/getting-height-and-width-of-image-in-java-without-an-imageobserver) 
The reason is because I will ultimately be loading my image from a JFileChooser. This is also why I can't just use constants for the Height and Width. I don't know which picture the user will be wanting to use.

Also, I don't feel like I should post my code for these two reasons

A) My code is not anywhere close to being a SSCCE piece of code: http://sscce.org/

B) This is such a general question that I feel my code would be too specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getWidth(java.awt.image.ImageObserver))

> Determines the width of the image. If the width is not yet known, this method returns -1 and the specified ImageObserver object is notified later.

This basically means that if the `Image` is not fully realised (as it is generally loaded in a background thread), the `ImageObserver` will be notified when the value is known.

A better solution would be to make use of the `ImageIO` API as the `read` method won't return until the image is fully loaded (and realised) or throws a `IOException` if the image can't be loaded.

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

If you "really" have to use `Image` and `Toolkit` to load them, then you should also have a look at [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html), but since `BufferedImage` (which is returned by `ImageIO.read`) extends `Image`, there really isn't much need

Comment: But I am doing the ImageIO quite a while before this code is executed. When I need to get the height I will have already thrown away the location of the file.

Comment: Wait, how would ImageIO help me here, it seems that I will have to use `getWidth(ImageObserver observer)` at some point to actually get the width of the image.

Comment: So?  Use `BufferedImage#getWidth` and `BufferedImage#getHeight` instead, which won't need `ImageObserver`

Comment: `ImageIO` ensures that the returned image is fully loaded/realised, so you wouldn't need `ImageObserver`, but if all you had was a reference to `Image` you could never guarantee that it was fully loaded without an `ImageObsever` or `MediaTracker`

Comment: Thank you for that. Side question: Why does Buffered image also have an option to pass and ImageObserver into the method?

Comment: Because, as I said, it extends `Image`, it's a side effect of the inheritance

Comment: And the error would be?  What type is `backgroundImage`?

Comment: My IDE glitched, and It's fixed now. Comment deleted.